# Having issues printing 2 dimensional array by column

Tags: c++

The parameters of the question are a loop to print the 2 dimensional array, iArr, so that all 3 numbers in column 0 are printed and then on the next line all 3 numbers in column 1, etc. thru column 4. Print column by column. I also can only use cnt1, cnt2, and the array I listed, no other functions or variables (hence reusing cnt1) and I had to earlier make the Arr elements random numbers between 1 and 53.

I have some loops, but I don't think they're properly printing the rows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int iArr[3][5];

for (cnt1 = 0; cnt1 < 3; cnt1++)
{
    for (cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < 5; cnt2++)
    {
        iArr[cnt1][cnt2] = rand() % 53 + 1; 
    }
}



for (cnt1 = 0; cnt1 < 3; cnt1++)
{
    for (cnt2 = cnt1; cnt2 < 5; cnt2++)
    {
        cout << setw(5) << iArr[cnt1][cnt2] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you think it is printing properly?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be the first row when I looked over the data, https://imgur.com/a/YjVeBXU is the output, sorry for the other stuff. Above the line is ALL the data, below is what printed. I guess maybe I'm just dumb and this was the valid data...wow if so.

Comment: Basis of any test: never use random input. Use predicted input to compate output with known sample. Try, dunno, `iArr[cnt1][cnt2] = cnt1*10 + cnt2` and see qhat is goong on

Comment: dont use random numbers for testing and debugging, or at least use a seed that lets you reproduce results. Bugs that appear on a random basis are nasty, and by using random numbers all your bugs/problems will appear randomly

Comment: Agreed, but the assignment required random input, so I guess I could make it not random to test? But that's why random input.

Comment: Your output is as expected - you are skipping first `n` elements of each row, where `n` is the the index of row (a.k.a. `cnt1`)

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  `for (cnt2 = cnt1; cnt2 < 5; cnt2++)` should be `for (cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < 5; cnt2++)`.  [Then it prints just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/badcf0d842e221d2)

Comment: If I change it to cnt2 = 0, it does not print columns, it prints all the data by row though?

Comment: do you mean to print it transposed?

Comment: `for (cnt2 = cnt1; cnt2 < 5; cnt2++)` I think is incorrect; You may wanted `cnt2 = 0`.

Comment: "_If I change it to cnt2 = 0, it does not print columns, it prints all the data by row though?_" - I'm not sure I understand your question. Why do you think the bottom two loops should be different from the top two?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some typo, you need to update the counters in second nested loop(while printing)

```
for (cnt1 = 0; cnt1 < 5; cnt1++)
{
    for (cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < 3; cnt2++)
    {
        cout << setw(5) << iArr[cnt2][cnt1] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

This will print values columnwise. First 3 values of first column, next line then next 3 values in second column and so on...

Comment: I'm confused, 3 numbers in column 0 are printed and then on the next line all 3 numbers in column 1, etc. thru column 4. Print column by column. And neither output from cnt2 = 0 or what I had attains that?

Comment: Not sure, If i exactly followed you. Inner loop(for row, 0 to 2) executes for for each column(0 to 4) and hence prints all elements columnwise. iArr[0 to 2][0] then iArr[0 to 2][1] and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there's a typo in the loops that print:

```
for (cnt2 = cnt1; cnt2 < 5; cnt2++)
```

So I think you meant:

```
for (cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < 5; cnt2++)
```

- If you are allowed and using newer version of C++ then why you've not declared the loop variables inside the loops instead?
- Because it is safer and less error-prone and those variable are re-usable and easy to track and check. Also they are not depending on each other:

  ```
  for (int cnt1 = 0; cnt1 != 3; cnt1++){
      for (int cnt2 = 0; cnt2 != 5; cnt2++){
          //...
      }
  }

  for (int cnt1 = 0; cnt1 != 3; cnt1++){
      for (int cnt2 = 0; cnt2 != 5; cnt2++){
          //...
      }
      cout << endl;
  }
  ```

So here we've limited as much as possible the scope of these variables to  be more safer.